# Swift macros when creating Array from literals

Tags: swift, macros

For the code below:

```swift
let services: [MyServices] = [
    MyService(),
    #if DEBUG
    DebugService(),
    #endif
]
```

I get compiler error:

> expression failed to parse:
> error: MyPlayground.playground:375:5: error: expected expression in container literal
> #if DEBUG
> ^

> error: MyPlayground.playground:376:19: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
> DebugService(),
> ^
> ;

> error: MyPlayground.playground:376:19: error: expected expression
> DebugService(),
> ^

> error: MyPlayground.playground:378:1: error: expected expression
> ]

But the same code works in Objective-C

```objectivec
NSArray *array = @[
        @"11",
    #if DEBUG
        @"debug",
    #endif
        @"22"
    ];
```

Is this a compiler bug or expected behaviour ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the body of each clause in an `#if ... #else ... #endif` compiler directive must surround complete statements.

But with the implementation of [SE-308 `#if` for postfix member expressions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0308-postfix-if-config-expressions.md) in Swift 5.5 this directive has been expanded to be able to surround postfix member expressions.

So with a custom extension

```
extension Array {
    func appending(_ e: Element) -> Self {
        return self + [e]
    }
}
```

one can conditionally initialize an array like this:

```
let services = [
    MyService() ]
#if DEBUG
    .appending(DebugService())
#endif
```

Comment: I like your solution better than mine, even my mention of adding `services.append(extra_contents)` inside the `#if / #endif`. Voted.

Answer (score 4):

The `#if` / `#endif` constructs are not preprocessor macros like in C. They are compiler directives. They are part of the language.

In C, it runs the preprocessor on your source file, which results in a modified source file. That modified source file gets compiled.

Not so in Swift. In Swift, the compiler parses the source file and attempts to compile it.

---

### Edit:

To understand why what you tried doesn't work, think of the `#if / #endif` like a regular if statement. Would the following compile?

```
let debug = true
let services: [MyServices] = [
    MyService(),
    if debug {
        DebugService(),
    }
]
```

(Answer: No. That's not legal. You can't insert an if statement in the middle of the parameters of an array initializer. Same goes for an `#if / #elseif` statement.)

---

You can’t use an `#if / #endif` block to assemble fragments of a statement together.

You would have to create complete statements in both cases:

```
#if debug
    let services: [MyServices] = [
        MyService(),
        DebugService(),
    ]
#else
    let services: [MyServices] = [
        MyService()
    ]
#endif
```

(Or you could make `services` a var, and append `DebugServices()` to it inside an `#if / #endif`.)

---

### Edit #2:

Better yet, use a "postfix" `.appending()` as in @MartinR's excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.5 (Using Swift Playgrounds)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let service: MyService = {
        #if DEBUG
        return DebugService()
        #else
        return MyService()
        #endif
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

class MyService: MyServices {
    func resultHandler() {
        print("RELEASE")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
class DebugService: MyServices {
    func resultHandler() {
        print("DEBUG")
    }
}
#endif

protocol MyServices {
    func resultHandler()
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? That code does not compile in my Xcode 14.2.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, I edit my answer improve with the full implementation :)